# GRUB doesn't show Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Whenever I boot into my system, Linux directly boots. If I press <kbd>shift</kbd>, GRUB shows only Linux, not Windows. Here are results of `fdisk` and `update-grub`. I think I have installed Linux the wrong way.

```
$ fdisk
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

$ update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
  No volume groups found
done
```

Comment: fdisk doesn't list GPT partitions very well.  Use the command `parted -l` and update your question.

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log.

Answer (score 2):

First I tried with `sudo os-prober` and `sudo update-grub` and it didn't recognize my windows.

Finally I solved this problem following steps of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Install boot-repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Push "Recommended repair"
And put in a terminal some commands as it suggested.

I think my Grub doesn't recognize windows due to a bad shutdown, and it solved the problem.

I hope this help you.