# Window boot file (bootmgfw.efi) might be overridden in Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm just new to Linux

I'm using HP Envy 13, installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu.
After installed Ubuntu, I had to press F9 to get to window boot manager, which is inconvenient so I had done some changes.

I wanted to use grub, but currently grub didn't show Windows option

First, I tried with `sudo os-prober`  and `sudo update-grub`, it found Window boot files, add done but I still couldn't see Window option on grub

Second, I tried after wisbucky's comment in [How do I get my HP laptop to boot into grub from my new efi file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file)

`$ sudo efibootmgr -v`

`$ sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi`

`$ sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`

And then it got worse. I restarted and found in grub **Window OS Manager** entering will refresh the grub.

(At this point, I didn't check whether F9 when start can go to Window)

Next, I have tried create Custom EFI choice to go to Windows 10 `bootmgfw.efi` in grub, but apparently something has been overridden in former steps so now I got choice in grub but when enter Windows 10 choice it refresh grub.

I went back to F9 and chose Windows option but instead it went to grub.
I think my bootmgfw has been replace by grubx64.efi

I also try repair boot by

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
in:
[GRUB doesn't show Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758830/grub-doesnt-show-windows-10)

it repaired successfully but result is still the same.

I tried to copy back `$ sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` but not working.

Totally screwed it up and don't know what next step should be to able to start windows again, I'm really apprreciate if any can help.

My current `bootmgfw.efi` file status:

[image: bootmgfw.efi status]

Comment: Years ago with early UEFI and difficult to boot sytems, we did suggest copying grub or shim to be the Windows boot loader. And it only worked for a short time, and only working  Windows can only be booted from grub and entry prevented booting Windows from UEFI if Windiows has issue. Or do not do that. Restore Windows UEFI entry: See IV: and restore Windows entry: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win Use your drive, do not just copy example.

Comment: thank you @oldfred, I'm very new to Linux that I can't even understand your suggestion in your link post(clear as it was). I'm gonna read it carefully before making any change.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   Boot-Repair will not fix Windows issues. But may show details, so we can give you exact command for your configuration. The efibootmgr commands default to ESP - efi system partition being sda1, but many Windows use sda2 or 3, so you have to be explicit. see also: `man efibootmgr`

Comment: @oldfred please see my report. thank you very much for your help
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YznZhRqFG3/

Comment: It looks like you have both correct Windows & Ubuntu boot entries in UEFI. Can you directly boot both from UEFI boot menu? HP - escape + F9 for boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios setup  Many with HP have needed UEFI update and then could only change boot order in UEFI/BIOS setup & boot tab. Grub also only boots working Windows, so fast start up in Windows must be off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I just tried it again.

F9 to UEFI boot menu:  it has Windows & Ubuntu, but both options will lead to grub menu.

@fast start up Windows: may be it's on but I couldn't boot into Windows now.

Comment: You show this, which is Windows boot file: "EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi" Did you then change BCD to boot grub by default? Do not know how to change back without booting into Windows as you cannot edit BCD from Linux. You will need your Windows repair/recovery disk or installer with repair/recovery console. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156795/windows-hard-disk-read-only-now-windows-is-removed?noredirect=1#comment1925839_1156795 & http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options